# A list of math puzzle sites that require little knowledge beyond first year college math, just a lot of creativity?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, online-resources

A while back I found IBM's Ponder This website.  http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/

What is wonderful about that site is that a large number of the problems there don't require advanced math.  A small number can even be solved by intelligent, committed, and creative high school students.

Aside from that site and some sites that post interesting problems from Math Olympiads, I'm not aware of similar types of problems or websites.  Someone mentioned Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net/) but that site also require comp sci knowledge and I am interested in math only.

I appreciate it if you could share with me any resources that might be helpful to me.

Edit: no it's wider in scope than the polfosol thread suggested (as my example of IBM Ponder This implies); in addition, unlike the suggested thread, it DOES include calculus (basic differentiation/integration as taught in intro calculus, which where I live, is taught optionally in last year of high school and as mandatory in first year of science programs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Favorite Math Competition Problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45603/favorite-math-competition-problems)